# Understanding the services and containers in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to apply the best laravel practices regarding the services + containers.

Usually when I need to use a method anywhere in my app, I do that :

```
class PersonneController extends Controller {

private $personne_service;
private $role_service;

public function __construct() {
    $this->personne_service = new PersonneService();
    $this->role_service = new RoleService();
}
    
/**
 * Renvoi la liste des personnes d'une école de la personne connectée
 * @return 
 */
public function getListePersonnes(Request $request, $id_ecole = null)
{
    if ($id_ecole == null){
        $id_ecole = Auth::user()->id_ecole;
    }
    
    $liste_personnes = $this->personne_service->getListePersonnesMultiRecherches($request->all());
```

See the last line to use a method in an other class. It works fine and I have understood the mechanic !

Now I would like to do the same thing using services and containers. Here what I do :

step 1 : create a service provider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\PersonneService;

class PersonneServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('PersonneService', function ($app) {
        return new App\Services\PersonneService();
    });
}
}
```

step 2 : declare this container into my app/config file :

```
'providers' => [

   // ....
    App\Providers\PersonneServiceProvider::class,
   

],
```

step 3 : I use this method anywhere in my app. For example in a controller : (see the commented lines vs the previous code)

```
class PersonneController extends Controller {

// private $personne_service;
private $role_service;

public function __construct() {
    // $this->personne_service = new PersonneService();
    $this->role_service = new RoleService();
}
    
/**
 * Renvoi la liste des personnes d'une école de la personne connectée
 * @return 
 */
public function getListePersonnes(Request $request, $id_ecole = null)
{
    if ($id_ecole == null){
        $id_ecole = Auth::user()->id_ecole;
    }
    
    // $liste_personnes = $this->personne_service->getListePersonnesMultiRecherches($request->all());
    $personne_service = app()->make('PersonneService');
    $liste_personnes = $personne_service->getListePersonnesMultiRecherches($request->all());
```

It does not work. I have this error :

> Class PersonneService does not exist in Container.php (line 729)

My questions :

- what are the problems ? (I read the official doc + a lot of tutorials on this topic)
- is it really a good practice to do that ? or do you think that my first technique is good too ?